# how to write re- usable code in jquerymobile html5 without server side scripting?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, jquery-mobile

is there any way i can include files in jquery mobile making some code re-usable instead of writing redundant code everywhere ?

Like for every page i need to have a home button and a back button .... is there a way where i can specify these in a file and include them in every page. i know a hard way of doing this using javascript ... where i can put a div="header" and include a script that will later add content ...

```
    <div id="bookHotels" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">

            -----   include the header file to to make it reusable ----

    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>footer text</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
```

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to do this?

Comment: @farjam ..... i started using http://handlebarsjs.com/ ... i personally found it to work better for templating

Answer (score 3):

If you are using HTML (`.html`) pages and do not have Server-Side-Includes hooked-up then you can use a JavaScript template (which is not too difficult). An added benefit of templating with JavaScript is that there is less over-the-wire data being transferred so the pages will download faster. It's a good idea to use templates if you find yourself re-coding the same thing over and over.

Here is an example of adding content to each page's header when the page is created by jQuery Mobile:

```
$('[data-role="page"]').live('pagecreate', function () {
    var $header = $(this).children('[data-role="header"]');
    $header.html('<div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li></ul></div>').trigger('create');
});
```

Another option is to use `<iframe>` tags with the `seemless` attribute (added in the HTML5 specification). Here is a doc link: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_iframe.asp

> Seemless: Specifies that the iframe should look like it is part of the
>   containing document

```
<div data-role="header">

        <iframe seemless="seemless" src="/path/to/header.html"></iframe>

</div><!-- /header -->
```

Comment: No there is no html 5 include like php ? ... i am aware of these two ways ... but just curious isn't the JQuery way of doing it a little weird . Nevertheless it works ... Thanks for the help Jasper :) ...

Comment: I remembered the updated `<iframe>` tag for the HTML5 specification, it includes the `seemless` attribute, check-out the link I added to my answer.

Comment: Seamless iframe does not work very well as content would not be enhanced. This solution did not work as-is for me, but pointed me in the right direction, thanks!!! I'll post the solution that works for me below. Even though it has been a long time since the question was asked, it is still an issue with JQM and it took me some time to figure out the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me based on Jasper's answer using js template principle. All the other answers to similar questions that use 'load' or similar technics do not work correctly as the html is not enhanced correctly and other issues.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', function () {
    // use document so that it triggers for all new pages
    // use pagebeforecreate so that JQM can enhance the html after it is inserted in the DOM
    // use 'on' instead of 'live' as 'live' is deprecated and does not work in jquery 1.9.1
    // $(this) is the current document here so have to use 'find' instead of 'children'
    $(this).find('[data-role="header"]').each(function () {
        // $(this) is now the header
        // if we have already inserted the html, we should not do it anymore
        if ($.trim($(this).html()) === "") $(this).html('<div data-role="navbar"><ul><li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li><li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li><li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li></ul></div>');
    });
});
```